# How do i create javascript for loops that create multiple variables with a different value each time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I am trying to create a JS program that compiles all presidents names, VPs, and dates served, to then be put into an html table which I am not asking about currently.

I am a javascript beginner and am using a package to search a presidents first name and then pull the information from the dictionary that is printed.

My issue is the let statement. I need to create a for loop that creates a let statement with the last name of every president (or president number), and assign it a value of the package function searchPresidents("**presidents first name**"). How can i create this for loop and then make sure that all the variables are created and have the correct information for me to print out as I did with the variables below the first let statement.

Code:

```
import {presidents} from "us-presidents";
import {searchPresidents} from "us-presidents";



let trump = searchPresidents("donald");

console.log(trump)


let startYear = trump[0].term["startYear"];
let endYear = trump[0].term["endYear"];
let name = trump[0].name;
let wikipedia = trump[0].wikipedia;
console.log("Starting year: " + startYear);
console.log("Ending year: " + endYear);
console.log("Name: " + name);
console.log("Wiki: " + wikipedia);
```

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(trump)`?

Answer (score 0):

It should be what you need.

```
for (let i=0;i < trump.length;i++){
    let startYear = trump[i].term["startYear"];
    let endYear = trump[i].term["endYear"];
    let name = trump[i].name;
    let wikipedia = trump[i].wikipedia;
    console.log("Starting year: " + startYear);
    console.log("Ending year: " + endYear);
    console.log("Name: " + name);
    console.log("Wiki: " + wikipedia);
}
```

For your second question, just depend on where you run your program.

It is because you label your question as node.js related, there are 2 possibilities.

1. Run in the command line e.g. node *yourProgram.js*, in this case, you need to study the use of the file system module, and just write HTML tag and the president's information into the output file.
2. You want to output the HTML table to the browser, you need to study how to use the express module to start a web server, and then study how to write ejs file, finally using the DOM interface to create the HTML table.

Comment: Thank you for the response! This will work for all the presidents but i am wondering how i can then put this information into an HTML table. Each table row having 4 table data’s: Name, Vice president, Start and end term, and wikipedia link. Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to create an HTML file only? Or put it on the internet?

Comment: I want to make an HTML table with each presidents information being a table row